# using setinterval and events not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, setinterval

im using setinterval to auto-refresh my website nevertheless i have an input box that every time page gets refreshed it clears data

```html
<td>
  <input id="numero" name="numero" type="text" 
     onfocusin="focusFunction();"     
     onfocusout="blurFunction();">    <!---current input-->
  <br>
```

```
myinterval = setInterval(function() {
  $("#panel").load(location.href + " #panel>*", "");
}, 3000);


var x = document.getElementById("numero");
x.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction, true);
x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction, true);


function myFocusFunction() {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
}

function myBlurFunction() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#panel").load(location.href + " #panel>*", "");
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: This is expected behavior.  You must explicitly setting the value of an input field in your source, it will not set them from the previous values.

Comment: there is no **declaration** of `myinterval` element.

Comment: Do you really want a new interval every time the input element is blurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTES**

You can use the following code to cache your data in the browser and on refresh it will put it back. But make sure you run `clearCacheData` or `clearAllCache` after you have saved the data somewhere otherwise it will hang around in the browser for a long time.

**HTML**

```html
<input id="numero" name="numero" type="text">
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```js
// save data to localstorage
function cacheFunction(inputElement) {
    if (!inputElement || !inputElement.id) return false;
    localStorage.setItem(inputElement.id, inputElement.value);
    return true;
}

// get data from localstorage
function uncacheFunction(inputElement) {
    if (!inputElement || !inputElement.id) return false;
    const value = localStorage.getItem(inputElement.id);
    if (value) inputElement.value = value;
    return true;
}

// delete data from localstorage
function clearCacheData(inputElement) {
    if (!inputElement || !inputElement.id) return false;
    localStorage.removeItem( inputElement.id );
    return true;
}

// Delete all localstorage data
function clearAllCache(){
    localStorage.clear();
    return true;
}

// handle cache event
function processCacheEvent({ target } = {}) {
    return cacheFunction(target);
}

// On document load make sure all inputs cache data on input
// if a page refresh happens, return all data to inputs
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    // Find all inputs
    const fields = [
        ...document.body.getElementsByTagName("input"), 
        ...document.body.getElementsByTagName("select"), 
        ...document.body.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
    ];

    // loop over inputs
    for (const field of fields) {
        // return saved values
        uncacheFunction(field);

        // save value on changes
        field.addEventListener("input", processCacheEvent);
        field.addEventListener("change", processCacheEvent);
    }
});
```